# How to get a chat id by phone number in Telegram?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I created a Telegram Bot using `BotFather`. My point is to notify users about sale events in the system. I can notify them when I know exactly their `chat_id` directly to private messages. How should I get their `chat_id` using their mobile number? I have an idea of getting `chat_id` when they subscribe into my group, but I don't know whether if it's correct way or not.

**I edited my question. I'll be really appreciate if my question has got more correct.**

Comment: Well since you asked, I reverted my DV, but please include a [mcve] of what you tried so people will stop DVing your question

Comment: Look at https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.getContacts. You can filter the results of the API call using the mobile number. The chat id is in the User vector

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Could u please include a piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Telegram **bot** API to notify your users (I see you mentioned `telegram-bot` in tags), the [documentation page](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans) says:

> Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first.

So in order to communicate with particular user bot **must** receive a message from him first and then you can get `chat_id` from received `Message` [object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message).

Comment: I have created a bot using BotFather

Comment: @КамиловТимур alright - now a user should send a message to your bot. User can find a bot by its name like @ blalblabla_bot. You can ask `BotFather` for bot's name.

Comment: I can't get `chat_id` without client's message to the bot or subscribing, can I?

Comment: No, you can't. This was made because otherwise bots can send spam to any telegram user.